# Jquery onclick function is repeating itself when it should only run once

Tags: jquery, function, button, repeat

I'm trying to add a previous-page and next-page button to a webpage, but when I click on the next-page button it jumps 3 pages ahead. I added an alert so I could see what was happening, and the page number is getting incremented 3 times; the alert pops up 3 times in a row before loading the new page, and each time the page number in the alert box has been incremented.

```
$(".nextPage").on("click", function (event) {
    var page = parseInt($(".page-num").val());
    page++;
    alert(page);
    $(".page-num").val(page);
    $(".submit-search").click();
});
```

Here are my page buttons:

```
<button type="button" class="prevPage"> < </button>
<button type="button" class="nextPage"> > </button>
```

Here is the field that is getting updated (it is the only item with that class):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PageNum, new{@class = "page-num"})
```

Why is the function incrementing page-num.val 3 times instead of once like it is supposed to?

Comment: what language is that? `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PageNum, new{@class = "page-num"})`?

Comment: if you click it again, does it happen 4 times? 5 times? my guess is you're rebinding it.

Comment: @MightyPork This is ASP.NET MVC Razor templating engine syntax, using C#

Comment: No, it repeats exactly 3 times every time I click. What's causing it to rebind, and  how do I fix that?

Comment: @KevinB, that was it! I don't really understand what was happening, but I put $(".nextPage").unbind() before my onclick code in my script and it's working now. Thank you!

Comment: that may be because you set the click handler multiple times. It doesn't replace the old one, it just adds them.

Comment: My guess, the template is been calling/access three times, so, the `click` event is binding multiple times. Try and set the alert outside the `$.on(click)` to debug

Comment: Always avoid binding events inside of events, unless said event removes all existing events or elements that said events were bound to.